# Android Studio adb server Connection reset by peer

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug, platform-tools

I set up a new Ubuntu installation and after that my adb is not working correctly.
Normally adb would recognize my emulator but when i startup my Computer i believe it does not start an adb server. When i type in "adb devices" it states the following Error:

```
adb: failed to check server version: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Connection reset by peer
```

After that i can do a "adb server".

When i did this command i see my device. But when i spam "adb devices" sometimes i get multiple offline emulators. like a lot (20).

It is really unreliable to work with this erros because sometimes it does not get recognized by the logcat. So i have to restart everything.

I havent found any solutions to it. "adb start-server" brings up the same Connection reset by peer error when i try to run it before i do "adb server".

> Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 Version 34.0.4-10411341 Installed
> as /home/pha/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb Running on Linux
> 6.2.0-33-generic (x86_64)

Do you have any solution?

Comment: adb is never started on computer start-up, it is always started on-demand, e.g. when you start Android Studio or by other programs that make use of adb and have the capability to start adb (not sure if the Android emulator does start adb).

Comment: multiple adb's installed? perhaps studio is finding a different one. Leave studio out and test everything from cli first.

Comment: i only installed adb thru Android Studios SDK Manager (Android Platform-Tools). But i already tried to delete this and use the "standalone" installation of adb thru apt install adb. in both cases i made sure i have only one installation at a time.

Comment: I got the same error 2 weeks ago, probably after upgrading the packages. Besides that, my Chrome also broke for localhost with 'Connection reset by peer'. I could resolve the last one by completely disabling ipv6 using systemctl, but adb still doesn't work.